# Laravel 5.2 Find a Model Based on a Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having an issue with writing an eloquent query for a search function in my project.
Here are my database tables/models:

```
artist
| id | name         |
---------------------
| 1  | Van Gogh     |
| 2  | Michelangelo |

art
| id | title        |
---------------------
| 1  | David        |
| 2  | Starry Night |

art_artist
| id | art_id | artist_id |
---------------------------
| 1  | 1      | 2         |
| 2  | 2      | 1         |

style
| id | title        |
---------------------
| 1  | Sculpture    |
| 2  | Painting     |

art_style
| id | art_id | style_id |
--------------------------
| 1  | 1      | 1        |
| 2  | 2      | 2        |
```

One artist `hasMany` art pieces, one art piece `hasMany` styles, and also `hasMany` artists. I have verified that the relationships work correctly. I also have a simple form that returns ids as a `GET` request with the variables `artist` and `style`.

So, I want to do two things in my function: First, check if the variables in the request are set (I can already do this). Then, ***USE ELOQUENT*** to query the `art` model based on the results of the form.

Here's an example: A user searches for a Sculpture by Michelangelo. The function queries the art database for any piece that is a sculpture by michelangelo and returns it as an `art` model.

The trouble is, I have absolutely no idea how to query the database based on the id of a related model. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do the query. First, I have to tell Eloquent I want to retrieve the `artist` model along with the `art`, *THEN* I can use `whereHas`:

```
$art = Art::with('artists')->whereHas('artists',function( $query ){
    $query->where('artists.id',1);
})->get();
```

Comment: Don't forget you can always use joins if you need to. In this case not as elegant but always an option.